# PHP - Opening modal content from another page and passing variable

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to open a modal in one page, called stores_list.php which is populated with data from another page called admin_store_view.php. I need to pass a variable to admin_store_view.php but for some reason I can't figure out how to achieve that.

Inside stores_list.php I have the following line of code

```
<td> <a href='admin_store_view.php' class='dt_link_text ajax_forms' data-id='$store_id1'  data-target='#testModal' data-toggle='modal'> $store_name </span></td>
```

and the modal definition

```
<div class="modal fade text-center" id="testModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div style="width: 1300px; right:350px;"class="modal-content">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then inside admin_store_view.php I am trying to fetch the ID that is passed in the data-id definition

```
$store_id   = htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]);
```

but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. After that I have the rest of the code for the modal and that seems to be working fine, apart from the fact that I can't get the correct results from my queries because the $store_id variable is 0.

Why is the variable not updating when the modal is opening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a querystring to the page you reference in the `href` like this

```
<td><a href='admin_store_view.php?id=<?php echo $store_id1;?>'  data-id='$store_id1'  data-target='#testModal' data-toggle='modal'> $store_name</td>
```

Comment: That did work. I have tried that before and it was giving me an error, no idea why. I think I might've been using <span> instead of <a> tag and possibly that caused an issue. Thank you! :)

Comment: It did work now, it hasn't before when i tried it but I think I had my tags incorrect. All good now :)

Answer (score 0):

try this 
instead of pass from `data-id` pass through `url`

like below

```
<td> <a href="'admin_store_view.php?id='.$store_id1.'" class='dt_link_text ajax_forms'> $store_name </span></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant get the value of id using `data-id`. As you're using `GET` method, you should attach the value of id with your URL.

```
<a href="admin_store_view.php?id=<?=$store_id1;?>">$store_name</a>
```

And also don't forget to put closing tag properly.

```
<td> <a href="admin_store_view.php?id=<?=$store_id1;?>" class='dt_link_text ajax_forms' data-id='$store_id1'  data-target='#testModal' data-toggle='modal'> $store_name </a></td>
```